# How to modify web environment entry in GlassFish 4

Tags: java, jndi, glassfish-4

In my `web.xml` od my `webapp` application I have following element:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>aMessage</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>Hello World</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

EJB in this web application can read it:

```
final InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
final Context env = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");
System.out.println("MSG: " + env.lookup("aMessage")); // prints Hello World
```

Now I am trying to change that value with `asadmin`:

```
martin@bono:~/glassfish4/glassfish/bin$ ./asadmin set-web-env-entry --name=aMessage --value=test webapp
Previous env-entry setting of aMessage for application/module webapp was overridden.
Command set-web-env-entry executed successfully.

martin@bono:~/glassfish4/glassfish/bin$ ./asadmin list-web-env-entry webapp
Reported 1 env-entry setting
aMessage (java.lang.String) = test ignoreDescriptorItem=true //
Command list-web-env-entry executed successfully.
```

Unfortunately my EJB still prints the old value "Hello World", even after re-enabling this webapp or restarting webserver.

I've also tried to `set-web-env-entry` for names not defined in `web.xml` and also played with `--ignoredescriptoritem` parameter, but nothing helped. Enumerating whole environment also shows no additional or changed web environment entries, but shows he old one plus many other objects not related to this problem:

```
final NamingEnumeration<Binding> enu = env.listBindings("");

while (enu.hasMore()) {
    final Binding binding = enu.next();
    System.out.println(binding);
}
```

**What I am doing wrong?**

Comment: I have no modules, only web application. I've tried to redeploy it and it should also restart it.

Comment: I've changed value of `<env-entry-value>` and EJB prints it. But I want to access value set with `asadmin`.

Comment: I've tried also with false. I've tried all combinations.

Comment: I couldn't help you, just upvoted it, good luck

Comment: After some trial and error I felt like raising [this one](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21352) for you, sry & welcome!

Comment: Maybe it is because some cache. Try to clean the temporary data from glassfish. I am not sure, but I guess you can remove the directories: generated and applications. They are inside of your domain directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug - but I have another solution for your needs. You can use custom resources which are available in glassfish. You have to declare custom resource in domain.xml

```html
<resources>
    <custom-resource factory-class="org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.PropertiesFactory" res-type="java.util.Properties" jndi-name="test/properties">
      <property name="aMessage" value="Hello World"></property>
    </custom-resource>
</resources>
```

then you can use it in the code

```
public class Environment
{

  public String getProperty() {

      InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
      properties = (Properties) ctx.lookup("test/properties");
      if(properties == null) {
          return "default value - hello";
      }

      return properties.getProperty("aMessage");    

  }

}
```

The one disadvantage of this approach is that custom resources are global for whole domain. But this solution has advantage you can change resources by using asadmin and admin web console also.